# temporarily disable login using one specific ssh key

Tags: ssh, authentication, openssh, public-key-authentication

On my server, I have several public SSH keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I would like to temporarily block/disallow/deactivate one key. I want to prevent the user to log in using this key now. but I might want to reanable it later (i.e. I don't want to delete the key entirely).

What is the correct/recommended way to do it?

Shall I just put a comment `#` at the beginning of the line in `authorized_keys`, in front of the key?

To clarify, I don't want to block a specific user. One user account is shared among several people, each person connecting with his own SSH key. I want to block one specific SSH key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could prefix the key with a forced command that tells the user what's going on.  For example:

```
restrict,command="printf 'Your key has been disabled\n'" ssh-rsa AAAAB2...19Q== joe@example.net
```

or for Openssh before v7.2:

```
command="printf 'Your key has been disabled\n'",no-pty,no-port-forwarding ssh-rsa AAAAB2...19Q== joe@example.net
```

Then they get:

```
$ ssh servername
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Your key has been disabled
Connection to servername closed.
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can just put `#` (or any other character, as long as the initial entry e.g. `ssh-rsa` is no longer valid), before the relevant line.

If you do that, and the system allows for plain text password logins as well, the user will be prompted for a password to login. So you might want to check that there is no (known) password associates with the account.